# "Error Encountered After PHP 8.3 Update on IIS Server"

Tags: php, iis, phpspreadsheet

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator.php** on line **135**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator.php** on line **153**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator.php** on line **145**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator.php** on line **171**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\ColumnIterator.php** on line **125**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator::current() should either be compatible with Iterator::current(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator.php** on line **55**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator::next() should either be compatible with Iterator::next(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator.php** on line **73**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator::key() should either be compatible with Iterator::key(): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator.php** on line **65**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator::valid() should either be compatible with Iterator::valid(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator.php** on line **83**

**Deprecated**: Return type of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev_iscoms\ordful\Classes\PHPExcel\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Iterator.php** on line **45**

Recently, I updated my PHP version to 8.3, and I'm encountering errors. I'm using an IIS server.

Comment: These aren't errors - they are _deprecation notices_. They simply warn you that something in the code will stop working in a future PHP version. Nothing is going wrong with your current code. If you don't want these notices to be displayed, you can turn them off in your PHP settings, or have them logged to a file instead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting, and https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration83.deprecated.php are relevant

Comment: See also https://stitcher.io/blog/dealing-with-deprecations, https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/php-8-x-understanding-what-the-deprecation-notices-mean/  and elsewhere